# How to get data from Postgres tables (many to many)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to link the article tables and tags. I created 3 tables

```
create table Articles (
  Id serial primary key,
  Title char(64),
  Descriptions text
);

create table Tags (
  Id serial primary key,
  Name char(64)
);

create table ArticlesTags (
  ArticleId integer not null references Articles(Id),
  TagId integer not null references Tags(Id)
);
```

How can I now correctly formulate a sql-request to receive an article and all the tags to it?

Comment: A simple JOIN query. Please post your code, your data set and your wished result set

Comment: Please remove one of two tags, postgres or mysql

Comment: I think it's PostreSQL. Removing MySQL tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the three tables:

```
SELECT a.title,
       array_agg(t.name) FILTER (WHERE t.name IS NOT NULL) AS tags
FROM articles a
   LEFT JOIN articlestags at ON a.id = at.articleid
   LEFT JOIN tags t ON at.tagid = t.id
WHERE a.title = 'whatever'
GROUP BY a.title;
```

Comment: Thanks, works, and how to make that tags were output by an array?

Answer (score 2):

As a slight variation on the answer by @Laurenz (+1), we can use left joins in case a given article might not even have any tags listed:

```
SELECT a.Title, COALESCE(t.Name, 'NA') AS tag_name
FROM Articles a
LEFT JOIN ArticlesTags at
    ON a.Id = at.ArticleId
LEFT JOIN Tags t
    ON at.TagId = t.Id
WHERE
    a.Title = 'some title';
```